# Can Wordpress support Website (19GB database) Should I move Our Wordpress Website to a custom one using Laravel or any other PHP framework?

Tags: php, query

QUESTION: Should we migrate our website to a custom build?

PROBLEM:

We run a WordPress website that currently has 19GB of MySQL Database data aside from images.

We are facing issues such as site speed, lagging, and sometimes server time issues.

We have moved the server to a Dedicated server, but the issue still persists. The site is currently sitting on a dual Xeon Processor with 8 Cores and 16 Threads, 64GB of RAM, and 1TB of SSD.

The hosting company suggests database query optimization as there as lots of slow queries running.

Also due to the way WordPress is designed it's not built for efficient query optimization.

Can anybody kindly advise the best solution?

NOTE: We have made so many changes, like caching (Redis, Nginx, etc), scanning for malware, using Cloud DNS, reducing plugins, changing plugins, and themes, and even deactivating all plugins, etc...

Comment: WordPress itself isn't necessarily the problem. 19gb in a database is enormous no matter what platform you're querying it from. Reducing the amount of data in the database, such as cleaning out old post revisions and options, is most likely to help this situation. Your host is right, optimizing queries may help, but that's going to depend on how often they're running and what they're doing. In this type of scenario I would say starting from scratch with a fresh custom theme and adding data and plugins in small increments will give you a better idea of what exactly can be done to help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's well appreciated.

Comment: the types of queries you're running have a huge impact on how big you can make your database and its performance, it's less that your database is big and making it slow, and more that your queries may not scale. Why is it 19GB? And what are the slow queries that are lagging? Be specific, this isn't a discussion forum and you need to ask a question that can be answered concretely with facts and not opinions that you could mark as the canonical correct answer

Comment: In all likelihood, it's a mixture of `meta_query`/`meta_value`/`'order_by' = 'RAND'`/or a `NOT` type parameter, just because you _can_ write a query doesn't mean that's how you're meant to do it, and stuffing the post meta table with everything then running queries to find/group/filter/search posts is expensive and bad practice but unfortunately also popular

Comment: Please note that DB cleanup of unused tables (left by inactive plugins) and cleaning wp_options table should help. Try wp-optimize plugin. If you already did - its the largets DB size i have heared of, ever.